# How to emulate Sink in akka streams?

Tags: scala, akka, akka-stream, reactive-streams, scala-streams

I have a simple "save" function that is using `akka-stream-alpakka` `multipartUpload`, it looks like this:

```
  def save(fileName: String): Future[AWSLocation] = {

    val uuid: String = s"${UUID.randomUUID()}"

    val s3Sink: Sink[ByteString, Future[MultipartUploadResult]] = s3Client.multipartUpload(s"$bucketName", s"$uuid/$fileName")

    val file = Paths.get(s"/tmp/$fileName")

    FileIO.fromPath(file).runWith(s3Sink).map(res => {
      AWSLocation(uuid, fileName, res.key)
    }).recover {
      case ex: S3Exception =>
        logger.error("Upload to S3 failed with s3 exception", ex)
        throw ex
      case ex: Throwable =>
        logger.error("Upload to S3 failed with an unknown exception", ex)
        throw ex
    }
  }
```

I want to test this function, 2 cases:

1. that multipartUpload succeed and I get AWSLocation (my case class) back.
2. that multipartUpload fails and I get S3Exception

so i thought to spy on multipartUpload and return my own sink, like this:

```
  val mockAmazonS3ProxyService: S3ClientProxy = mock[S3ClientProxy]

  val s3serviceMock: S3Service = mock[S3Service]

  override val fakeApplication: Application = GuiceApplicationBuilder()
    .overrides(bind[S3ClientProxy].toInstance(mockAmazonS3ProxyService))
    .router(Router.empty).build()

  "test" in {
    when(mockAmazonS3ProxyService.multipartUpload(anyString(), anyString())) thenReturn Sink(ByteString.empty, Future.successful(MultipartUploadResult(Uri(""),"","myKey123","",Some(""))))

    val res = s3serviceMock.save("someFileName").futureValue

    res.key shouldBe "myKey123"

  }
```

the issue is that i get `Error:(47, 93) akka.stream.scaladsl.Sink.type does not take parameters`, i understand i cant create sink like this, but how can i? 
  or what could be a better way testing this?

Comment: See: https://doc.akka.io/docs/akka/2.5/stream/stream-testkit.html

Comment: @BennieKrijger I did, but couldnt find where i can emulate just a sink...

Comment: Move the save function to a class or trait and pass the sink as an argument. When testing you can pass a TestSink to this class/trait.

Comment: i succeed emulate it like this with testkit ```val sinkUnderTest1: Sink[ByteString, Future[MultipartUploadResult]] = Flow[ByteString]
  .toMat(Sink.fold(multipartUploadResult)((x,_) => x))(Keep.right)``` and i pass sinkUnderTest1 after the thenReturn. but now I dont know how to emulate when the future of multipartUploadResult fails..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Consider redesigning your method `save` so it becomes more testable and injection of  specific sink that produce different outcomes for different tests is possible (as mentioned by Bennie Krijger).

```
  def save(fileName: String): Future[AWSLocation] = {
    val uuid: String = s"${UUID.randomUUID()}"
    save(fileName)(() => s3Client.multipartUpload(s"$bucketName", s"$uuid/$fileName"))
  }

  def save(
    fileName: String
  )(createS3UploadSink: () => Sink[ByteString, Future[MultipartUploadResult]]): Future[AWSLocation] = {

    val s3Sink: Sink[ByteString, Future[MultipartUploadResult]] = createS3UploadSink()

    val file = Paths.get(s"/tmp/$fileName")

    FileIO
      .fromPath(file)
      .runWith(s3Sink)
      .map(res => {
        AWSLocation(uuid, fileName, res.key)
      })
      .recover {
        case ex: S3Exception =>
          logger.error("Upload to S3 failed with s3 exception", ex)
          throw ex
        case ex: Throwable =>
          logger.error("Upload to S3 failed with an unknown exception", ex)
          throw ex
      }
  }
```

The test can look like

```
class MultipartUploadSpec extends TestKit(ActorSystem("multipartUpload")) with FunSpecLike {

  implicit val mat: Materializer = ActorMaterializer()

  describe("multipartUpload") {
    it("should pass failure") {
      val result = save(() => Sink.ignore.mapMaterializedValue(_ => Future.failed(new RuntimeException)))
      // assert result
    }

    it("should pass successfully") {
      val result = save(() => Sink.ignore.mapMaterializedValue(_ => Future.successful(new MultipartUploadResult(???))))
      // assert result
    }
  }
```